# Script to get List of logged in users

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, terminal

I'm writing a Shell script to get a list of logged in users, i want to show a list like this one :

```
The user AAA is on tty3
The user BBB is on pts/0
```

Here's what i've written so far :

```
echo "The user " | who | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}' | echo " is on " | who | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'
```

but in only shows the second column, i get this :

```
tty3
pts/0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try doing this in single one `awk` statement:

```
who | awk '{print "The user " $1 " is on " $2}'
```

By doing that many piping, you are sending first one's input as another ones output. Hence you are losing previous data and at last only the output of `who | awk '{print $2}'` is coming out.

Answer (score 0):

Last users

```
last | cut -d " " -f 1 | sort | uniq
```

Last users detailed

`last | uniq | column`

who's logged in (username only)

```
who | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort | uniq
```

short who column

```
 who -su | sort | uniq | column
```